# RoR rspec error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rspec

Web development newbie here. Today's the first time I got my hands on rspec and it's giving me some confusing error messages. Everything was working fine until I closed down the RoR command line to take a break. When I came back it began giving me errors as shown in the image link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcFbY.jpg

I've reinstalled the bundle and the rspec gem to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have in your `static_pages_controller.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is a syntax error from Ruby, not from Rspec. Run `ruby -c app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` to see what the syntax error is (in particular, it looks like you have an extra `end`, or a missing `end` in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel kinda stupid because I double checked the static_pages_controller.rb file to make sure it doesn't contain an extra end. When I checked again after reading your comment, it was just there.